# What's the best way I can import/display lyrics for iTunes on a mac?

Tags: macos, itunes, music, lyrics

I'm currently using [iClip Lyrics](http://www.1thdream.com/), but apparently it's being discontinued. It can't import lyrics from certain lyrics sites (such as wikia) because they've used some javascript/iframe mix to make copy/pasting difficult.

I was wondering if there were other options that are better at importing lyrics automatically as well as displaying lyrics. Bonus points for solutions that handle unicode encoded characters too, since a good portion of my music library is asian.

Comment: +1 Besides a third party app, there is not way to *display* lyrics in iTunes.  I used to use iClip Lyrics as well, until they were force to stop. It was really a great app, especially if you have an iPhone/iPod Touch - as the lyrics are displayed when playing a song.  I have looked around for other options with no luck. You could write an Apple Script to help with some of the tasks - Good Luck

Comment: Thanks debug. I'm not discounting 3rd party apps. If there's a marginally better iClip-like app, then that would work great for me. There seems to be a ton of dashboard widgets that do this, but I don't use Dashboard, and wouldn't want to constantly swap to it to see/retrieve lyrics.

Comment: I agree, I would not use dashboard either. iClip Lyrics really had a great app..

Answer (score 1):

I really like http://www.eternalstorms.at/gimmesometune .

Auto-adds lyrics and has a lyrics display pane, as well as correcting covers and providing hotkeys. Oh and it's free (donations accepted).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a post on my blog to showcase my findings regarding this question. Check it out:

[Software to add Lyrics to MP3 files ID3 metadata](http://www.leniel.net/2011/01/software-add-lyrics-mp3-files-metadata.html)